Does "if and only if" takes a comma?
Does the sentence

I'll go to the theater if and only if it rains.

takes a comma before the and?
There are many rules about the comma before the word and (Oxford commas come to mind) and joining two clauses, etc. but none of them seem to apply to this particular case

I have seen it in examples where an extra emphasis, by pausing, is really called for like in The software will function correctly if, and only if, all dependencies are installed properly. In Mathematics, where it is used a lot, one almost never place any commas because the meaning is well-understood and no emphasis is necessary. My question is, if there are any rules that would support it.

I agree with ishtar.


I'll go to the theater if and only if it rains.

I have not come across the use of commas before and or bracketing and only if in
if and only if.
That would be a wrong usage.
We consider two types of commas.
Joining commas are for connecting two independent clauses and are hence not applicable here; the second part of the sentence is not an independent clause.  *I'll go to the theater if, and only if it rains. is hence invalid.
Bracketing commas are for setting off optional phrases, and their use will void the logical connective if and only if, a logical biconditional. I'll go to the theater if, and only if, it rains. no longer retains the meaning of the original example.  The necessary condition is lost.
Wikipedia

An "if and only if" statement is also called a necessary and sufficient condition.


"Madison will eat the fruit if and only if it is an apple" is equivalent to saying that "Madison will eat the fruit if the fruit is an apple, and will not eat the fruit if it is not an apple".

